# Pages overlaps on navigation in Ionic4

Tags: cordova, routes, ionic3, angular5, ionic4

I have developed an application using ionic4. I am facing an issue during navigation the pages overlaps like below give picture. I am using `NavController` for navigation.

```
    public editUserProfile() {
       this.menuCtrl.close('side-menu');
       this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/home/edit-profile');
  }
```

Any solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the issue,
This is not because of the navigation using `NavController`, in my case I was using `ion-header` without color. This was causing issue. Use like below

```
<ion-header color="<set your color>"></ion-header>
```

Anyone who is facing the issue like this, please check whether the background is set or it is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic 3 Navigation method not working in Ionic 4. You need to implement angular routing concepts here. Referee this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/navigation/angular

Comment: Hi, Ionic4 supports navigation like that. It removed this.navCtrl.push()

Comment: No, Ionic 4 not support navigate like that, that was one of the reasons of the change from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4

Comment: This is so because of the lazy loading and the difficulties to use deep links, in Ionic 3  you must use IonicPage to take advantage of its functionalities, but in Ionic 4 that is implicit in the navigation system with the Angular router.

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping content while routing to other pages could be due to default routing animation.

Try disabling "animated" property to false in ion-router-outlet.

```html
<ion-router-outlet [animated]="false" id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
```